# Truth outside of god

Tags: reference-request, theology

I am looking for resources about this matter, thank you for your help!

I start from a theist viewpoint (god exists). God created existence, before that, though, it is true that he was "there", but that suggests that truth is outside of god, which seems weird?

Comment: In the usual monotheism the entire creation is outside of God, he is [transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_(religion)) to it. It does not mean that truth predates creation, the statement "it is true that he was before that" can only be made after that. What is a little weird is that God does not exist, he is beyond existence. This is usually dealt with by distinguishing between "exists" and "is", God does not exist but he is, see e.g. [Plotinus and Aquinas on God by Kimbler](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=ohiou1275619376&disposition=inline)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to read the pdf.

Comment: It is unclear what you’re asking, but I don’t want to vote to close the question without the opportunity for revision.

Comment: "God" is a superstition

Answer (score 3):

## The existent

'**God created existence**' : (a) God created everything that is not-God, e.g., the world, persons, time, space. Perhaps this is better expressed as 'God created all existing non-God things'. An oddly worded statement but from God-as-Transcendent viewpoint, not otherwise objectionable.

If God created Godself and is *causa sui*, self-caused, as **Spinoza** put it, then God created everything that is not-God (under (a)) and also Godself (under (b)).

## Existence

**It does not follow, however, that because God created all *existing things*, that therefore God created *existence*.** Whatever existence may be, it isn't and can't be (as least so it seems to me just now) identical with existing things.

Someone might say (**Kant** notwithstanding) that existence is a first-order property that objects can and do have - as opposed for instance to being a second-order property of first-order objects. The laptop on which I am writing undoubtedly exists and so possesses the property of existence. Therefore, since God created (a) and (b), which *ex hypothesi* exist, God created - caused to exist - the property of existence which all existing things have.

Parenthesis: I have taken a slight historical liberty with Kant, who denies that existence (or as one should more properly say, 'exists') is not a *predicate*. But in denying that existence is a predicate Kant is also denying that it is a property. So I interpret. Check out Kant, Critique of Pure Reason, 2nd ed., 1787: B626.

The question is whether existence **is** a property. If it isn't then neither God nor anything else caused it to exist.

As a first take, consider the statement : 'The flower is blue, is located at 52.572576 latitude and -0.2427336 longitude, is perennial ... and (to complete the list) also exists. Is existence really a property that the flower has in addition to all its other properties? Also, if existence is a property, could something, X, exist and have absolutely no other properties?

We could explore the possibility that existence is a second-order property of first-order objects but in a short answer I must leave that exploration to others.

## Truth outside God

> God created existence, before that, though, it is true that he was "there", but that suggests that truth is outside of god, which seems weird?

The paradox is, I take it, that if God caused existence, God must have existed already ('before that') else how could Godself cause existence ? But if God existed already, then there was already existence (i.e., God's), so God cannot have caused it.

I may (my fault) be wrong but this is how I understand you.

So where do we go from here?

**Atemporality**

The first step, I suggest, is to look at your phrase, 'before that'. Suppose that God is atemporal - outside time. There are at least two possibilities :

1. God's existence is instantaneous. Since an instant is durationless, it cannot occupy time. It has no temporal parts. This is hardly likely to illuminate the nature of any God you have in mind.
2. God is eternal. This might mean any of several things, e.g. divine everlastingness. Here I'll assume it means that God is a non-temporal or timeless entity. In other words, God does not exist in time - God is atemporal. To explain further:

> Because an eternal entity is atemporal, there is no past or future, no
> earlier or later, within its life; that is, the events constituting its life
> cannot be ordered sequentially from the standpoint of eternity. But,
> in addition, no temporal entity or event can be earlier or later than
> or past or future with respect to the whole life of an eternal entity,
> because otherwise such an eternal life or entity would itself be part
> of a temporal series. (Eleonore Stump and Norman Kretzmann, 'Eternity', The Journal of Philosophy, Vol. 78, No. 8 (Aug., 1981), pp. 429-458: 434.)

If God is atemporal then there is no before or after in God's life, therefore from the divine standpoint the idea of there being anything before or after God causes existence is nullified.

From the human standpoint by contrast, since we think temporally we suppose that God,  within time, caused existence and that it's reasonable to ask how God could have caused existence since God must have existed 'before that' in order to do the causation.

The problem is best approached, so I have suggested, with the assumption that there is no 'before' or 'after' in the nature of an atemporal God. So from the divine standpoint your problem does not arise. The problem does arise within our own temporal standpoint, and we can only deal with it by assuming that God creates time and existence simultaneously. Hence there was nothing 'before' existence. I am aware that 'simultaneously' is a temporal notion but as temporal beings we cannot avoid temporal thinking.

## References

George Pattison, Eternal God / Saving Time. Published by Oxford University Press, United Kingdom, 2015. ISBN 10: 0198724160 / ISBN 13: 9780198724162.

Paul Helm, Eternal God: A Study of God without Time, Published by Clarendon Press, Oxford, 1988. ISBN 10: 0198244789 / ISBN 13: 9780198244783.

Eternity: A History. Published by Oxford University Press Inc, United States, 2016.
ISBN 10: 0199781869 / ISBN 13: 9780199781867.

Answer (score 1):

> truth is outside of god, which seems weird?

When the word 'god' does not indicate 'the ultimate' and you analyze it that way, your statement -- 'Truth is outside of god', is true. So it is not weird.

When you believe that 'God is Truth.', that Truth can't be outside of God.  There are slight differences while 'defining' the term 'God' by different philosophies.  Just to avoid confusion and to give more clarity to God / the Ultimate Truth, some philosophies denote it using other terms.

E.g.: http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=731&parent=632&format=html

I believe the implications (I mean, prayer related) are the same and the difference is only in technical usage. Philosophies (some or many) might have tried to tackle this issue.  If not so we wouldn't have heard the statement, "God is Truth." Instead, we'll have to conclude that "God is not the Ultimate; it is only a lower truth."  And this is the same thing you doubted. And its result would be that some people who have a very subtle, sagacious and sharp intellect would not be satisfied with a mere-god. They would seek the Ultimate Truth.

Comment: You are tackling a difficult topic and I am not sure I understand fully what you say. (This is not a criticism.) But +1 for confronting the question. Just a very small point: 'When the word 'god' does not 'the ultimate' and you analyze it that way'. Is a word missing here between 'does' and 'the ultimate' ? All the best - Geoff

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas: Thanks. It was a typo. I have added the missing word.

Comment: Good - I realised it was nothing major. Best - Geoff